# How to query id not in condition with another table typeorm

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Here is the query

```
SELECT * from tableA WHERE tableA.id NOT IN (SELECT tableB.a_id FROM tableB);
```

Same query how to write using TypeORM typescript?
Below is code, I tried which is not working

```
this.createQueryBuilder('tableA')
.where(`tableA.id != :id`, { id })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const tableBqry = tableBRepository
       .createQueryBuilder('tableB')
       .select("tableb_id");

const tableAqry = tableARepository
       .createQueryBuilder('tableA')
       .where("tableA.id NOT IN (" + tableBqry.getSql() + ")");

const results = await tableAqry.getMany();
```

This method will work fine for the above-mentioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can select IDs from `tableB` first, and then use the IDs you've got (I assume that they are mapped and stored in `var ids: string[]`) to make a query for `tableA`.

```
this.createQueryBuilder('tableA')
  .where(`tableA.id <> ALL(:ids)`, { ids })
```

Comment: without selecting those ids leftJoinAndSelect will it work?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try left joining and then where some field in tableB is null.